walsender process and connections via bouncer in Postgres is not using TLS Encryption
I have been testing TLS encryption for my Postgres database. All the external client connections are using SSL for encryption. I tried to query the pg_stat_ssl view, which will list the information about active SSL connections. When I used this query, I couldn't find the walsender process in the result. The query I used:
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_ssl ;

Is the encryption disabled for the walsender by default? Or am I making a mistake?
I am using PGBouncer as a connection pooler. I am facing the same issue for connections via Bouncer. The configurations I used for Bouncer SSL encryption is as follows,
[databases]
 postgres = host=localhost port=5435 dbname=postgres
 testdb = host=localhost port=5435 dbname=testdb auth_user=pgbouncer
 [pgbouncer]
 listen_port = 9010
 auth_file = userlist.txt
 auth_query = select p_user, p_password from lookup($1)
 auth_type = md5
 listen_addr = *
 logfile = pgbouncer.log
 pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
 max_user_connections = 100
 pool_mode = transaction
 ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
 client_tls_sslmode = require
 client_tls_cert_file = server.pem
 client_tls_key_file = server.key
 server_tls_sslmode = require
 server_tls_cert_file = server.pem
 server_tls_key_file = server.key

When I am connecting to Postgres via Bouncer I am getting this output,
Logs from pgbouncer.log
testdb/USER@IP:58646 login attempt: db=testdb user=user1 tls=TLSv1.3/TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)

Which means the client encryption is working...
As of my knowledge, 'client_tls_sslmode' is used for SSL encryption with the external clients and 'server_tls_sslmode' is used for SSL Encryption between Bouncer and Postgres. Please correct me if I am wrong..
I am using PG 14.3, Bouncer 1.20v and am using TLS encryption only, not certificate authentication.
(There is not problem in replication and connections via bouncer, I want to ensure that the connections are using encryption)

I can't reproduce the absence of the row.  For me the walsender process is listed in pg_stat_ssl.  It will have an appropriate value under the 'ssl' column, and by my testing this value is accurate.  I tested under 14.9, not 14.3. (now tested under 14.3, works the same)

Streaming replication can use an encrypted connection just like any other connection. If the server supports encrypted connections (ssl = on) and the replication connection is via TCP (not via Unix sockets), PostgreSQL will choose an encrypted connection by default.
To force streaming replication to use an encrypted connection, use sslmode=require in the primary_conninfo parameter on the standby server:
primary_conninfo = 'host=... port=... user=... sslmode=require'

You may need to restart the standby to make it establish a new connection.

Edit to adapt to the new information (pgBouncer is in use):
If you do what I said above, the connection between the standby and pgBouncer will be encrypted. But in pg_stat_ssl, you see the connection between pgBouncer and the database.
Recommendation: don't use pgBouncer for the replication connection.

I tried using this option in 'primary_conninfo'. The replication is established. But I am not getting the process ID of Wal_sender when using 'pg_stat_ssl' view. Also I am using bouncer as a connection pooler. I enabled both 'client_tls_sslmode' and 'server_tls_sslmode'. The 'pg_stat_ssl' view is not showing pgbouncer pid when connecting to postgres. Is there any other function (or) view to test this to ensure the encryption in replication and connections via bouncer?

"Also I am using bouncer as a connection pooler". Ah, interesting detail. Why didn't you mention that in the question? If you want that covered, you'd have to edit the question and tell us details about how all that is set up.

I edited the question to understand the issue better. Please check

'don't use pgBouncer for the replication connection.' I am not using pgbouncer for replication. I am using pgbouncer for connecting to postgres servers. Normal streaming replication is used between primary and standby. For streaming replication, I have added the above command as 'sslmode=require'. The replication is working. But the data is not visible under pg_stat_ssl view. The same for bouncer, in bouncer logs it is showing that it is using encryption. The connection between Client and Bouncer is encrypted but what about the connection between Bouncer and Postgres?

The simple answer is: write sslmode=require into the connection strings in the pgBouncer configuration. But really, you shouldn't do that. Also, don't use localhost connections. Use Unix socket connections and don't waste performance. That's secure.
